# MediaPlayer.setDataSource Exception: NullPointerException Reason: Java.io.File.fixSlashes(filename)

Tags: android, file-io, media-player, android-sdcard, file-descriptor

I have crated and application which plays a video from a file on the sdcard. The application starts on the boot of the mobile device. When the device restarts, the application waits until the sdcard is mounted, then it takes the path of the file on the sdcard and tries to play the file using MediaPlayer api. But the application crashes with below logs. **The app runs fine if the user starts the application manually while the device is running and not booting.**

```
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at com.sherbet.taxi.FullVideoActivity.setUpVideoFrom(FullVideoActivity.java:225)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at com.sherbet.taxi.FullVideoActivity.onCreate(FullVideoActivity.java:112)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-22 18:53:39.700: W/System.err(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 18:53:39.730: E/MediaPlayer(1302): error (1, -2147483648)
09-22 18:53:39.830: E/MediaPlayer(1302): prepareAsync called in state 1
09-22 18:53:39.830: W/System.err(1302): java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-22 18:53:39.830: W/System.err(1302):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
09-22 18:53:39.830: W/System.err(1302):     at com.sherbet.taxi.FullVideoActivity.play(FullVideoActivity.java:187)
09-22 18:53:39.830: W/System.err(1302):     at com.sherbet.taxi.FullVideoActivity.surfaceChanged(FullVideoActivity.java:354)
09-22 18:53:39.830: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:558)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:85)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:173)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1828)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4223)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-22 18:53:39.840: W/System.err(1302):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-22 18:53:39.850: W/System.err(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 18:53:39.860: E/MediaPlayer(1302): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

The code is:

```
File file = new File(videoUrl);
file.setReadable(true, false);
Utils.ShowLogMsg("filepath: " + file.getAbsolutePath()
                + " exists: " + file.exists());
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
FileDescriptor fd = inputStream.getFD();
Utils.ShowLogMsg("file length: " + file.length());
**

mPlayer.setDataSource(fd, 0, file.length());
        inputStream.close();

**
```

The application occurs at the highlighted line in the code. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Comment: ManuToMatic, dont just edit, please guve the answer also. Its urgently required.